# How to update the QT Mainwindow at each loop in mainwindow.cpp

Tags: qt, loops, mainwindow

My main.cpp look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

An in my mainwindow.cpp I want to show a different image at each loop in "while", so it would look like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    image = load_an_image
    int i=0;
    while (i<15)
    {
        show image in the MainWindow
        waitkey (wait until I press a key or wait some time)
        do something to this image for the next loop
        i++
    }
}
```

However the Mainwindow does not show up until the "while" is finished and I cannot find how to show the MainWindow at each loop.

Can anyone give me any advice ?

Comment: You can handle keyReleaseEvent on your main window, and once you press/release a key, you can change the image and so on.

Comment: Create a slot which morphs you image and displays it. Connect this slot with keypress signal or QTimer::timeout() signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delay handling the image by using a Qtimer. Something like this: -

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer::singleShot(5, this, SLOT(timeout());
}

// create as a slot in the MainWindow derived class
void MainWindow::timeout()
{
    image = load_an_image();
    int i=0;
    while (i<15)
    {
        // show image in the MainWindow
        // waitkey (wait until I press a key or wait some time)
        // do something to this image for the next loop
        i++
    } 
}
```

However, it would be better handled by loading the first image and then reacting to key events, rather than waiting directly in the main thread...

```
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* keyEvent)
{
    if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Space) // use the space bar, for example
    {
        if(m_imageFrame < 15)
        {
             // update the image
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QMainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(keyEvent);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I will try this, it is the first time I use QTcreator so I didn't know what to use in the first place.

Comment: I cannot make it work... I tried the first solution but it is not working. I think it will still wait the end of the "while" to show the MainWindow. I would like the mainwindow.cpp to interact with the main.cpp
Because right now all the code in mainwindow.cpp is computed and then  w.show();  shows the interface... But after all the loops are done.

Comment: Ignore the 1st example, and handle the keyReleaseEvent. Gui applications, such as those with Qt are event based and you should be thinking of working with events this way.

Answer (score 2):

GUI will not update itself until gui thread is free of other tasks. However, you can force it using

```
qApp->processEvents();
```

Following is example of very bad coding style, but that might be what you want.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    qint8 k = 15;

    using namespace Qt;

    QPalette pal;
    QColor col = red;

    while (k--)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(250));
        pal.setBrush(w.backgroundRole(), QBrush(col));
        w.setPalette(pal);
        col = col == red ? blue : red;

        qApp->processEvents();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

To run this, you will have to add QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 to your '.pro' file.
And if you want to understand things better, i recommend to read about qt events.